# Liquibase : Migrate.sql does not check precondtions

Tags: liquibase

I use liquibase to generate SQL files based on the changeset . But when I am using liquibase:updateSQL , it is not checking for preconditions before generating the SQL file

I have a preconditions saying to check if the table exists , before creating the table .

In this scenario even though the tables are present the 'create table SQL statement is still getting generated.'

Where as when i run liquibase:update goal this precondition is checked properly .

So does not liquibase check for precondition while generating the sql file?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest raising a ticket against the liquibase project. I'm guessing pre-conditions are difficult to render as pure SQL. For example the table might exist exist on your database instance, but might be missing on another... When running the migration via liquibase it can check this condition using java. A SQL based solution would presumably have to generate PL/SQL on Oracle, but wouldn't work at all on database that don't support stored procedures. Interesting problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have found an answer already, but just in case this might help:

http://forum.liquibase.org/topic/unexpected-behaviour-of-preconditions-with-updatesql

onSqlOutput="TEST" attribute for the precondition sounds like what you are looking for.

Just be careful with the the preconditions you write or when to test them while generating the updateSQL. Preconditions that rely on previously applied patches that might have not been executed yet in your instance could cause errors.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Might help to provide some code. Especially your precondition to allow other to evaluate if it is an issue.